# iOS mail client doesnt render html email

Tags: html, ios, ruby-on-rails, email, mailchimp

Using MailChimp to fireoff emails from my rails platform.  It uses only a body with inline styling and no js.  It renders fine on all web clients and mobile clients (iOS and Android) except for iOS's native mail client.  When pulling up the email in the iOS native mail client, i can see the email for about 50-100 ms, then it disappears, leaving just a white blank page. It looks as if its getting "pop up blocked".  The content itself is 3 colored divs filled with text and images.  Any one ever experience anything like this? I have scoured the web (and will continue to do so).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sending .html and .text versions of the email?

Comment: I have not, that would replace with just plain text correct?

Comment: Yes. If your mail program is blocking html it will look for a plain text version

Comment: Okay well i have emails from other companies in my inbox that have html and styling, and mine shows up for a split second before going white (so its rendered at some point).  Doing plain text isnt really solving my problem thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @NickM, that may be a good solution for the time being. Can you point me in the right direction for info on how to render plain text on mobile clients?

Comment: Not sure how to do it based on a mobile client, but if you send both the html and text versions in your mailer the correct one will render by default.

Comment: Found the solution, Posted below, thanks for the responses

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found the answer.  Apples iOS mail client is not big on loading external style sheets.  Infact, it shuts out all the html if you try to include that anywhere in your html.  I had this line:

```
        %link{:rel => :stylesheet, :type => :"text/css", :href => "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"}
```

When i took it out, everything worked, css and all!

Hope this helps someone!